# How to get all collections in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my query is like this

```
var db = new Db('NodeZMQ', new Server('192.168.3.110', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true }));

db.collection('clsSession', function (err, collection)
{
    collection.findOne({ "code": { "$in": ["eventCode"] }, "Venue.allowSales": true, "status": "O", "Venue.companyCode": "companyCode" }, function (err, document)
    {
        console.log(document);
    });
});
```

It gives one document.
Actually it has lot of documents..
Since i am using findOne it is like that..
how to get all matching documents ?
I am using node.js and mongodb.
I am new to mongoDB and node.js.

Comment: replace `findOne` with `find`

Comment: { db:
   { domain: null,
     _events: null,
     _maxListeners: 10,
     databaseName: 'NodeZMQ',
     serverConfig:
      { domain: null,
        _events: null,
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _callBackStore: [Object],
        host: '192.168.3.110',
        port: 27017,
        options: [Object],
        internalMaster: false,
        connected: false,
        poolSize: 5,
        disableDriverBSONSizeCheck: false,
i did using find..
it is giving as above instead of collection

where i went wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collection.find(` instead of `collection.findOne(`. This returns a cursor object you can use to iterate over the results.

The cursor is an object with many methods. Those you will find most helpful are the methods [.hasNext()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hasNext/) which checks if there are still unprocessed documents and [.next()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.next/) which gives you the next document.

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = new Db('NodeZMQ', new Server('192.168.3.110', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true }));

db.collection('clsSession', function (err, collection)
{
collection.find({ "code": { "$in": ["eventCode"] }, "Venue.allowSales": true, "status":    "O", "Venue.companyCode": "companyCode" }).toArray(function (err, document)
{
    //here document is an array contains all the matching reocrds
    console.log(document);
});
});
```

This example based on assumption that you are using mongo-native driver but it helps to solve your problem.